# Ray: Parallel read of audio in chunks that preserves ordering

Tags: python, ray

I would like to use Ray to perform large scale inference on audio files. I would like to read each file in, chunk by chunk, perform inference on each chunk, and then write each file out chunk by chunk so that I never have to have an entire file in memory at one time. At the same time, I'd like to parallelize the operation so that multiple audiofiles could be processed at the same time.

I've created a datasource and a datasink that works if you load the entire file into memory at once. But I haven't figured out how to do it when you're loading a file in chunk by chunk and have to maintain the order and make sure you have all the chunks when performing the write operation.

```py
class AudioDataSink(RowBasedFileDatasink):
    def __init__(self, path: str, file_format: str, model_sample_rate: int, **file_datasink_kwargs):
        super().__init__(path, file_format=file_format, **file_datasink_kwargs)
        self.model_sr = model_sample_rate
        self.file_format = file_format

    def write_row_to_file(self, row: dict[str, Any], file: "pyarrow.NativeFile"):
        audio = row["audio"]
        if self.model_sr != row["original_sr"]:
            audio = soxr.resample(audio, self.model_sr, row["original_sr"])
        sf.write(file, audio, self.model_sr)


class AudioDatasource(FileBasedDatasource):
    _WRITE_FILE_PER_ROW = True
    _NUM_THREADS_PER_TASK = 8

    def __init__(
        self,
        paths: str | list[str],
        model_sample_rate: int,
        **file_based_datasource_kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(
            paths,
            file_extensions=["wav", "mp3", "flac", "ogg", "aiff"],
            **file_based_datasource_kwargs,
        )
        self.model_sr = model_sample_rate

    def _read_stream(self, f: "pyarrow.NativeFile", path: str, **reader_args) -> Iterator[Block]:
        try:
            audio, sr = sf.read(f, dtype="float32", always_2d=True)
        except RuntimeError as e:
            raise ValueError(f"Error reading {f}: {e}")

        if sr != self.model_sr:
            audio = soxr.resample(audio, sr, self.model_sr)
        audio = np.transpose(audio)
        builder = DelegatingBlockBuilder()
        item = {"audio": audio, "original_sr": sr}
        builder.add(item)
        block = builder.build()
        yield block
```

Comment: Are you asking how to modify code you already have, but have not posted?

Comment: Wasn't sure if they'd be helpful. Just posted them. I could also post non-ray code for reading in chunks, but that's not the problematic part. Instead it's properly allocating the parallelism and keeping track of individual files when writing.